# Ionic2 navbar coloring globally

Tags: ionic2

I just started to work with ionic v2 today and I am trying to color my app to match my preferences. While playing with the color variables gave some colors, I cannot find how to color every navbar to my preference although I can color them individually. What are the variables I should access in order to give all navbars the same color?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done as globally only sigle class can change your toolbar color gobally.

```
.toolbar-background{
     background-color: "color you want to give" !important;
}
```

or you can do seperately for each platform like

```
 .toolbar-wp-themecolor .toolbar-background-wp{

}
.toolbar-md-themecolor .toolbar-background-md{

}
.toolbar-ios-themecolor .toolbar-background-ios{

}
```

or if you want to control with global color variable then for each page you can use like

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar color="themecolor">
    <ion-title>Notifications</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

where themecolor can be defined in variable.scss

```
$colors: (
  primary:    #387ef5,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222,
  white: #ffffff,
  themecolor: #574D70
);
```